# Запись видео или картинок с веб камеры - как такое сделать и на чем?

Tags: c#, node.js, delphi, php, java

2 варианта:

**Вариант 1**

3 веб камеры и комп

Есть сайт на нем есть личный кабинет

При заходе в личный кабинет видны видео с этих 3-х камер, причем так что бы их было не записать к себе на комп

Так же видео записывается на жесткий диск в главном компе

**Вариант 2**

3 веб камеры и комп

Есть сайт на нем есть личный кабинет

При заходе в личный кабинет видны фотографии с этих 3-х камер, которые обновляются раз в 5 сек

Так же видео записывается на жесткий диск в главном компе

**Вопрос**

Как такое сделать?

Мои знания

php, mysql, javascript, delphi, nodejs

поверхностные знания

C#,java

Кто знает как такое сделать, напишите последовательность моих действий и то как такое реализовать с минимальными затратами

Comment: вариант 1 - 
> причем так что бы их было не записать к себе на комп

 невозможно.

Comment: записать на комп с личного кабинета

возможно не записать, уже давно есть технологии потокового видео

недавно попался сайт с фильмами онлайн, там нифига не записать видео к себе, потому что оно разбито на кучу потоков и каждый со своей сессией

Comment: кто скринкаст то запретит сделать ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решается эта задача так же, как и любая другая.  
1. Разбиваем задачу на более мелкие: 
1a. Гугл - Record video from webcam <любой язык программирования>   
1b. Гугл - stream video from webcam <любой язык программирования>  
1c. Гугл - multiple webcam video <любой язык программирования> 
2. Решаем каждую часть задачи